# how to disable disable shift key in fabricjs?

Tags: fabricjs

I have angularjs+fabricjs based application/module.
I want to disable swift key selection but it should allow group selection.

Can I do this in fabicjs? If yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

There is a function _shouldGroup in fabricjs

```
_shouldGroup: function(e, target) {
      var activeObject = this.getActiveObject();
      return e.shiftKey &&
            (this.getActiveGroup() || (activeObject && activeObject !== target))
            && this.selection;
    }
```

Change this to

```
_shouldGroup: function(e, target) {
      var activeObject = this.getActiveObject();
      return false;
    }
```